# Variable class call and namespace in PHP

Tags: php

Using a variable containing the name of a class then creating a new instance of that class, I have a question on the way I call the class in the variable. 
My code works:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\someEntity;

$entityName = "AppBundle\Entity\someEntity";
$instance = new $entityName();
```

Now, what I would like to do is change the `$entityName` variable for something more simple like `$entityName="someEntity";`

Anyone have any idea on how to do that? 
I am using PHP5.5

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: I hope my proposed way will help you out.